# How to store UIView in CoreData or UserDefaults

Tags: swift, core-data, uiview, uilabel, userdefaults

In my case I have a ViewController that client must create a `UILabel` , I want to store `UILabel` , when I used `UserDefaults` it returns `nil` :

```
extension UserDefaults {

      func setLabel(label:[UILabel],forKey key: String){
        let viewData: NSData?
        viewData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: label) as NSData?

        set(viewData, forKey: key)
    }

    func labelForKey(key: String) -> [UILabel]? {
        var view: [UILabel]?
        if let viewData = data(forKey: key) {
            view = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: viewData) as? [UILabel]
        }
        return view
    }  
}
```

Comment: My salutation for the laugh , it's first time in programming not in swift that i see someone wants to store a UI element  (I/O) , There is no use case that requires that , you need to store it's text  , the UI elements won't fly you can load them easily and set the stored text to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for `UserDefaults`, you can not store custom objects in the `UserDefaults`, only `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary` (or similar types in Swift), see documentation.

Do not store UI class - just store parameters you want to restore lately.